# $P(x,n) = \frac{x(n-1)!}{n^{x}(n-x)! }$ -- What is the name of this probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$
P(x,n) = \frac{x(n-1)!}{n^{x}(n-x)! }
$$

I'm having a really tough time describing what this distribution does, but it's simple in code.  So if you know code, then read on:

```
// example with n = 10
// keep incrementing x until it is greater than random number between 0 and 10
// note that the random number is generated after each iteration
var i = 0;
while (i++ < Math.random() * 10){};
i = i - 1;
// P(3, 10) = the odds that i will end up being 3
```

What is the name of this distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability mass function
$$
    p_m = \mathbb{P}\left(X=m\right) = \frac{m}{n^m} \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-m)!} [ 1 \leqslant m \leqslant n ]
$$
The pmf satisfies a simple recurrence equation:
$$
    \frac{p_{m+1}}{p_m} = \frac{n-m}{n} \frac{m+1}{m}  
$$
discrete distributions whose pmf satisfy first order difference equation with polynomial coefficients were studies by Katz (see [Johnson, Kemp, Kotz](http://books.google.com/books?id=JchiadWLnykC&dq=Katz+discrete+distribution&source=gbs_navlinks_s)), who considered them discrete analogs of [Pearson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution) family.

It remains to prove that the sampling procedure is correct. The probability of the event that the sampling code above yields $m$, is equivalent to the probability that
$$
   \mathbb{P}\left(U_1 > \frac{1}{n}, U_2 > \frac{2}{n}, \ldots, U_{m-1} > \frac{m-1}{n}, U_m < \frac{m}{n} \right) = \frac{m}{n}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1} \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right) = \frac{m}{n^m} \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-m)!}
$$
where $U_k$ are iid continuous random variables, uniformly distributed on the unit interval.

---

Actually this particular distribution is known as [Naor's distribution](http://www.expertsmind.com/questions/naor%27s-distribution-3018555.aspx), which arises in an urn model.

Comment: +1 It would also worth noting that for $\displaystyle F_m = - \frac{n!}{(n-m)! n^m}$ we have $F_{m+1} - F_m = p_m$ implying $$\sum_{m=1}^n p_m = F_{n+1} - F_1 = 0 - (-1) = 1$$ Thus verifying the normalization.