# Lottery in which your luck increases every turn, but resets once you win.

Tags: probability, lotteries

**Problem:**

Suppose a lottery exists in which your luck increases as you play. The probability of winning a prize starts at 1%. After every unsuccessful attempt, the probability of winning increases by 1% from your previous odds (so 1% becomes 2%). When a prize is won, the chance of winning is reset to 1%. What is the expected number of prizes that you will receive after 100 uses?

**What we know so far:**

So far we have tried recurrence formulas but failed to get a closed form answer.

Through a python script and brute forcing we have calculated the answer to be 7.8608…

We have also tried by viewing 1% as 1/100, we added up the fractions: 1/100 + 2/100 + 3/100... + 14/100, which yielded a sum of 105/100. Based on this calculation, the probability of winning appears to exceed 100%. To determine the number of times this outcome would occur within 100 attempts, we divided 100 by 14. But we again found a problem as we ended up with a sum of 105/100.

All of our answers lie closely to each-other but we have yet to find a concrete answer

We would appreciate any help that we can get!

Comment: Expected # of prizes $~= \dfrac{100}{A},~$ where $~A = ~$ the expected (i.e. average) # of tries per win.  Then, $$A = \sum_{n=1}^{100} n \times p(n),$$ where $~p(n)~$ equals the probability of winning on the $~n$-th turn.  Then $$p(1) = 0.01, ~p(2) = 0.99 \times 0.02, ~p(3) = 0.99 \times 0.98 \times 0.03,~$$ and so forth.

Comment: @NumberBasher No, my formula is only supposed to be applied to computing the **first** win.  The formula gets re-set after each win.  This is the foundation for computing $~A~$ which represents the average number of tries **before the first win**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147115/discussion-between-number-basher-and-user2661923).

Comment: You can  also solve numerically with a spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tfVDS32huSkNKL3_vUp0pQw1BNKWKEhm8eQYBX8RICc/edit?usp=sharing 
I doubt that there is some simple closed form formula

Comment: For what's worth: The distribution of each "run" (number of tries for each prize) is known as Naor's distribution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276013/px-n-fracxn-1nxn-x-what-is-the-name-of-this-probability/276067

Answer (score 2):

$\def\eqd{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Let $\ \frac{X_t}{100}\ $ be the probability of your winning on the $\ t$-th try. Then you will have won on the $\ t$-th try if and only if $\ X_{t+1}=1\ $. Your expected number of wins after $100$ tries is therefore
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{100}\Bbb{P}\big(\text{You win on the $\ t$-th try}\big)=\sum_{t=1}^{100}\Bbb{P}\big(X_{t+1}=1\big)\ .
$$
Now $\ X_t\ $ is a discrete, homogeneous, $100$-state [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), the entries of whose transition matrix are given by
\begin{align}
P_{pq}&=\Bbb{P}\big(X_{t+1}=q\,\big|\,X_t=p\big)\\
&=\cases{1-\frac{p}{100}&if $\ q=p+1$\\
\frac{p}{100}&if $\ q=1$\\
0&otherwise.}
\end{align}
If $\ \pi_t\ $ is the (column ) vector of probabilities of $\ X_t\ $ being in any given state:
$$
(\pi_t\big)_q\eqd\Bbb{P}\big(X_t=q\big)\ ,
$$
then
$$
(\pi_1)_q=\cases{1&if $\ q=1$\\
                 0&otherwise,}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\pi_{t+1}^T&=\pi_t^TP\tag{1}\label{1}\\
&=\pi_1P^t\ .
\end{align}
Your expected number of wins after $100$ tries is therefore given by
\begin{align}
\sum_{t=1}^{100}\Bbb{P}\big(X_{t+1}=1\big)&=\sum_{t=1}^{100}\big(\pi_{t+1}\big)_1\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^{100}\pi_{t+1}^T\pi_1\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^{100}\pi_1^TP^t\pi_1\ .
\end{align}
Because the matrix $\ P\ $ is sparse, with only two non-zero entries in every row, the recursion \eqref{1} can be used to calculate the vectors $\ \pi_{t+1}\ $ for $\ t=1,2,\dots,100\ $ quite quickly:
\begin{align}
(\pi_{t+1}^TP)_q&=\sum_{p=1}^{100}\big(\pi_t\big)_pP_{pq}\\
&=\cases{\sum_\limits{p=1}^{100}\frac{p\big(\pi_t\big)_p}{100}&if $\ q=1$\\
\frac{\pi_{q-1}(101-q)}{100}&if $\ 2\le q\le100$}\ .
\end{align}

The [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) script given below performs the calculations described above, and obtains exactly the same answer as Number Basher does with the Python script he gives in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733301/lottery-in-which-your-luck-increases-every-turn-but-resets-once-you-win/4733302#4733302).  To run the script, copy and paste it into the [online Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) and click on the "submit" button.

```
nt:=100;
n:=100;
oldpi:= ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,nt);
newpi:= ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,nt);
oldpi[1,1]:=1;

expw:=0;
for t in [1..nt] do
  for p in [1..n] do
    newpi[1,1]:=newpi[1,1]+p*oldpi[1,p]/n;
  end for;
  for q in [2..n] do
    newpi[1,q]:=oldpi[1,q-1]*(101-q)/n;
  end for;
  expw:=expw+newpi[1,1];
  oldpi:=newpi;
  newpi:= ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,nt);
end for;

print expw;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following python script:

```
def cache(function):
    cache = {}
    def f(*args):
        if args in cache: return cache[args]
        result = function(*args)
        cache[args] = result
        return result
    return f

@cache
def wins_average(turns_completed=0, probability=1):
    if turns_completed == 100: return 0
    return probability * (100**(100-turns_completed) + \
            wins_average(turns_completed+1)) + \
        (100-probability) * wins_average(turns_completed+1, probability+1)

print(wins_average())
```

we get that the exact answer is `7.86080126403229668198182908097394362384354574898764667238115242755521947164335122692038436352382356040222738777625219891364911130702970910977870565447613758476042568092806020045109899810694869084004791`. However, we have yet to get insight as to why this is.

Comment: Off-topic but just pointing something out in case it's useful: you don't have to write your own cache decorator. You can use `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)`

Comment: oh ok thank you, it doesnt matter in this case since time efficiency is not really important here. i just dont use libs much ig